# Can I access Static Variable which is declared in a static method in another class

Tags: java

I have a static variable which is present inside a static method. Can I access it from another class?

PFB my code: CellValue is the variable that I need to access in another class (Code 2 below).

Code 1:

```
public static String[][] getSheet(String dataSheetName) {
    String[][] data = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("./data/"+dataSheetName+".xlsx"));
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);   

        // get the number of rows
        int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum();

        // get the number of columns
        int columnCount = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
        data = new String[rowCount][columnCount];


        // loop through the rows
        for(int i=1; i <rowCount+1; i++){
            try {
                XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);
                for(int j=0; j <columnCount; j++){ // loop through the columns
                    try {
                        String cellValue = "";
                        try{
                            Cell cell1 = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0);   

                            switch (cell1.getCellType()) {
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                cellValue = cell1.getStringCellValue();
                                break;
                            }
                            cellValue = row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
                        }catch(NullPointerException e) {

                        }
```

Code 2:

```
public HomePage engagementDetails(String why, String who, String block, String streetname, String unit, String postalcode) {
        System.out.println("Not able to click");
        DataInputProvider dp = DataInputProvider.getSheet();
        if(getSheet.cellValue == "1") {
        clickbyXpath(prop.getProperty("AddNewForm.A9Yes_Xpath"));
        }
        else if (DataInputProvider.cellValue == "2") {
        clickbyXpath(prop.getProperty("AddNewForm.A9Yes_Xpath"));
        enterbyId(prop.getProperty("AddNewForm.A9Why_Id"), why);
        }
        clickbyXpath(prop.getProperty("AddNewForm.A10Yes_Xpath"));
        enterbyId(prop.getProperty("AddNewForm.A10Who_Id"), who);
        clickbyXpath(prop.getProperty("AddNewForm.A11No_Xpath"));
        enterbyId(prop.getProperty("AddNewForm.A11Block_Id"), block);
        enterbyId(prop.getProperty("AddNewForm.A11StreetName_Id"), streetname);
        enterbyId(prop.getProperty("AddNewForm.A11Unit_Id"), unit);
        enterbyId(prop.getProperty("AddNewForm.A11PostalCode_Id"), postalcode);
        clickbyXpath(prop.getProperty("AddNewForm.A12OTH_Xpath"));
        clickbyXpath(prop.getProperty("AddNewForm.A13Lang_Xpath"));
        clickbyXpath(prop.getProperty("AddNewForm.A13Photo_Xpath"));
        scrollPage();
        clickByName(prop.getProperty("AddNewForm.Next_Name"));
        return this;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to understand the context. The variable is in a static method. But do you know where your HomePage is initialized?

Answer (score 2):

No, local variables are limited in visibility to the code block that they are declared in, which in this case is the `try` block within the second `for` loop.

It is possible to declare a static class variable and gain access to that, i.e.

```
static String cellValue = "";
```

and you can afterwards assign a different string to the `cellValue` (note that Java strings are immutable).

Relying on (static) class variables and class methods is however considered code smell: something that hints at bad class design. If those class variables change value (changing the global state of the program) then that's considered *bad* code smell.

It is probably better to:

1. refactor the code and make the methods act on a class instance (i.e. without `static`);
2. separate the business logic and the UI layer.